# Why is the vote count off-center for locked questions?

Tags: bug, design, locked-posts

I was reading through a locked question when I noticed that the vote count (actually, the votes text) is off-center:

[image]

Why is this off-center?

Same problem for the answers:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the number and "votes" are left justified, but the bookmark icon is centered.

Comment: On the contrary, it looks like the number is correctly centered, but the word "votes" is left-aligned.

Comment: Possibly, for the same reason the word "votes" is there, while it's actually the score (upvotes - downvotes) and not the number of votes, because they didn't think through the design for locked questions.

Comment: Several people brought this up in the feedback thread before the feature was launched. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389650/170024) for example. I'd listen to this user since they seem to be a professional graphics designer. I mean, first ask for feedback from the community, which as it happens due to the nature of the site contains a significant amount of professional GUI/graphics designers. I dare guess that the person who re-designed the buttons is not one of them. Then they give you professional, high quality feedback for free. And then you ignore it and launch anyway...

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure what you're referring to.  The post you linked says nothing about locked posts (this is *only* a problem on locked posts, because the word "votes" is not present otherwise), and the problem [predates that post by years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425275/208273).

Answer (score 7):

It looks like this might've been introduced ages ago; I found the first occurrence in October of 2020.

On October 25th of '20, you can see it centered:

> [image: Locked Stack Overflow question viewed through the Wayback machine on Archive.org from October 25th, 2020, with the "votes" label centered under the post score number]

And then just 5 days later (the next available capture for [this particular locked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391)), on the 30th, it's no longer centered:

> [image: Locked Stack Overflow question viewed through the Wayback machine on Archive.org from October 30th, 2020, with the "votes" label left aligned under the post score number]